# Bamboo Branch Updater: Is it possible to build the branch isolated first and then merge with master and build again?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

I am having a bit of trouble with the [Branch Updater](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-plan-branches-289276872.html) feature of Bamboo.

If a new commit is pushed on a branch that is using the branch updater, Bamboo checks if there are new commits on the dependent branch(in my case the master branch) and if this is the case it merges the changes and runs the build.

However, if this build fails, it is hard to recognize, if the new code on the branch itself is broken or if it just could not be merged correctly with the master. Therefore I would like that in these cases the branch is build independently first and only if this build is successful, the changes on the master are merged in and the branch is build again.

Is this possible using the branch updater feature?

A workaround might be to use multiple build plans and use one to build all branches isolated and another plan to integrate everything using the branch updater.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, how did you get on with the answer provided below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Branch Updater" feature is to merge the code from master branch into feature branch **after a successful build of the master branch**.

However, currently there is **NO** straight forward option in Bamboo (except the workaround mentioned in your OP) to build the branch and auto merge only if the branch build is successful.

Typically, the developer runs the build in local and commit the changes to repository if the local build is successful. There are two things that can go wrong.

1) While running the local build, the latest code from feature branch is not available in local. Some of the repos like GIT would complain if the local doesn't match with HEAD revision, you need to update to HEAD before you commit the changes. In this case, you can run the build again to ensure there is no problem.

2) When the master code merges with feature branch, something could go wrong

I understand that still there is a gap which can be addressed to resolve the point 2.

You can create a ticket in Bamboo with detailed explanation of the use case to add this feature.